# Flink Statefun Bootstrap and State expiration

Tags: java, state, apache-flink, ttl, flink-statefun

According to [this page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.1/sdk/java.html#state-expiration) we have the ability to set TTL for state when using Flink Statefun v2.1.0.

We also have the ability to bootstrap state, according to [this page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-statefun-docs-release-2.1/deployment-and-operations/state-bootstrap.html).

First question is, bootstrap documentation does not mention state expiration at all. What is the correct way to do bootstrapping on states that have TTL? Can someone point me to an example?

The second question is, what happens if I set some state as expire after writing in 1 day and then bootstrap that state using 6 months worth data?

Is the whole bootstrapped state going to expire after literally 1 day?

If so, what can I do to have it expire 1 day worth of data after 1 day passes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if that data hasn't been modified since it was loaded, it will all be deleted after one day.

To expire one day's worth of data every day: After bootstrapping the state, you could send yourself a delayed message, set to be delivered one day later. When it arrives, delete the oldest data and send another delayed message.